# Complex regex patttern to select all users that are not part of a specific group

Tags: regex

I've been trying to write this regex selection pattern for about an hour now and I just can't wrap my head around how regex works with complicated patterns.

Basically I have a list of around 20k users where the data looks like this:

```
  d3c80ef4-ae3c-43dc-8cf1-2dd44db19612:
    group: []
    options:
      name: etcusername
  7cacfa27-da32-49d0-8c6f-f1dced07e8bb:
    group:
    - Duke
    options:
      name: username3
  2b5e7795-fba5-4ae0-9479-a1d14f3e4678:
    group: []
    options:
      name: username2
  e7f8ef7e-0e58-4142-ba0f-763be65e55e3:
    group:
    - Resident
    options:
      name: username1
```

Now, I want to blacklist specific 'groups' from being selected. Let's use "Resident" and "Duke" as examples, once I can figure out the regex ( or have help figuring it out :( ) I can fill in the rest of the ranks that I want to keep.

This is the regex I came up with so far, which just selects every line regardless of group :(

```
((?!Resident))((?s).+?(name: )(\S)*\b)
```

I think this is all the information I need to include here, I've just been trying so long and I need to move on from this. If any other information is needed please ask in comments and I will surely update the question with the information requested.

Comment: Environment/programming language? Sample data with Duke? Can a block have multiple group entries?

Comment: @NetMage I'm doing the match in notepad++, and yes. Updated with Duke.

Comment: What chunk of data are you trying to match?

Comment: @revo the regex I have now matches perfectly the chunks I want to match, it just doesn't ignore the match if group is duke/resident. My selection should be the entire chunk including the GUID of the user, unless they match those groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This matches from GUID to name: skipping over the excluded groups:

```
^  [0-9a-f]{8}(-[0-9a-f]{4}){3}-[0-9a-f]{12}:\R(^(?! +- (Resident|Duke)).+\R)+? +name: .+\R
```

Comment: This works in notepad++, why does it not work in regex101.com?

Comment: Matching multiple lines is one area where different Regex engines are very different. Notepad++ has a special character class I was recently introduced to `\R` that matches any end of line character. In other regex environments, you must match that diferently (e.g. in emacs use `^J` (Ctrl-J)). Online testers match specific environments, not always the same as the actual environment, especially when different OS are thrown in to the mix.

Comment: That's why I tested in Notepad++ :) - it can be tricky to match peculiarities of specific engines otherwise.

Comment: This regex doesn't introduce peculiarities that won't work in other flavors except `\R` which is a perl-compatible and regex101 default engine is PCRE too.

Comment: And yet it doesn't work in regex101 unless you turn on the m flag - which is apparently the (hidden) default in Notepad++. Again, multiline matching is tricky across environments.

Comment: That's not called *peculiarity* but the reason why `m` flag exists.

Comment: I like my answer better.

Comment: I don't like the assumption there couldn't be other options besides group, options and names, though mine does have the downside of excluding options that include Resident or Duke...

Answer (score 2):

Something like this ?

`/(?m)^\s*group:(?s:(?!\s*-\s*(?:Resident|Duke)(?!\S)).)*?^\s*options:\s*^\s*name:\s*(.*?)\s*$/`

https://regex101.com/r/jGU7Hk/1

Expanded

```
 (?m)
 ^ \s* group:
 (?s:
      (?!
           \s* - \s* 
           (?: Resident | Duke )    # Exclude these groups
           (?! \S )
      )
      . 
 )*?
 ^ \s* options: \s* 
 ^ \s* name: \s* 
 ( .*? )                       # (1) Name
 \s* $
```

---

**update** - with ID's

`/(?m)^\s*([a-fA-F\d]+(?:\s*-\s*[a-fA-F\d]+)+)\s*:\s*^\s*group:(?s:(?!\s*-\s*(?:Resident|Duke)(?!\S)).)*?^\s*options:\s*^\s*name:\s*(.*?)\s*$/`

https://regex101.com/r/TJKKIP/1

```
 (?m)
 ^ 
 \s* 
 (                             # (1 start) GUID
      [a-fA-F\d]+ 
      (?: \s* - \s* [a-fA-F\d]+ )+
 )                             # (1 end)
 \s* : \s* 
 ^ \s* group:
 (?s:
      (?!
           \s* - \s* 
           (?: Resident | Duke )     # Exclude these groups
           (?! \S )
      )
      . 
 )*?
 ^ \s* options: \s* 
 ^ \s* name: \s* 
 ( .*? )                       # (2) Name
 \s* $
```

Comment: That only matched one, and it didn't select the UIDs

Comment: It matched 2 in my demo, but if you want to select the UID it's simple to add it.

Comment: It isn't clear in your question you want to match all of them at once? I don't think that's possible with a single Regex... or do you mean using Find All?

Comment: @NetMage I want every chunk except those matching specific groups

Comment: @sln ah, you're right, but it's still not selecting the GUID's. My goal is to remove all of the users that don't have specific groups.